# adding multiple select and delete functions in android context menu

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, multipleselection

I'm quite new to android and I am trying to add **context menu** for my **listView** .So I followed the guide shown in android developer page and now if I press long an item from my **listView** I got the **context menu** appeared in action bar . What I want to add is that when i select more than 1 item , I want to show **count** in **context menu** . Additionally I like to **delete** selected items when I click bin icon in **context menu** .

I think it would be a bit efficient if you see my code . below is my code . it is just described in developer page

```
albumListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    albumListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    albumListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.album_context_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                long id, boolean checked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

I would be very happy if you can give some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

- MainActivity:

  ```
      package com.example.listviewexample;

      import java.util.ArrayList;

      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.graphics.Color;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.util.Log;
      import android.view.ActionMode;
      import android.view.Menu;
      import android.view.MenuInflater;
      import android.view.MenuItem;
      import android.view.ViewGroup;
      import android.widget.AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener;
      import android.widget.ListView;

      public class MainActivity extends Activity {

          ListView listViewObj;
          MyAdapter adapter;

          @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              ArrayList<String> listArgument = new ArrayList<String>();
              listArgument.add("Item 1");
              listArgument.add("Item 2");
              listArgument.add("Item 3");
              listArgument.add("Item 4");
              listArgument.add("Item 5");
              listArgument.add("Item 6");
              listArgument.add("Item 7");
              Log.d("listArgument", listArgument.toString());
              listViewObj = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
              adapter = new MyAdapter(this, listArgument);
              listViewObj.setAdapter(adapter);
              listViewObj.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
              listViewObj.setSelected(true);
              listViewObj.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {
                  int selectionCounter;

                  @Override
                  public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      return false;
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                  }

                  @Override
                  public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                      inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                      return true;
                  }

                  @Override
                  public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      switch (item.getItemId()) {
                      case R.id.action_delete:
                          selectionCounter = 0;
                          adapter.removeItem();
                          mode.finish();
                          return true;
                      default:
                          return false;
                      }

                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                          int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                      if (checked) {
                          selectionCounter++;
                          adapter.selectedItem(position, position);

                      } else {
                          selectionCounter--;
                          adapter.removeSelection(position);  
                      }
                      mode.setTitle("Selected :" + selectionCounter);

                  }
              });
          }
      }
  ```
- Adapter Class:

  ```
              package com.example.listviewexample;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.Iterator;
  import java.util.Set;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.graphics.Color;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
      HashMap<Integer,Integer> selectionValueMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
      Context vContext;
      ArrayList<String> DataValueList = new ArrayList<String>();
      public MyAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> DataValueList)
      {
          this.vContext = context;
          this.DataValueList = DataValueList;
      }


      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return DataValueList.size();
      }

      @Override
      public Object getItem(int position) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return DataValueList.get(position);
      }

      @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return 0;
      }
      public void selectedItem(int postion ,int flag)
      {
          selectionValueMap.put(postion, flag);
          notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
      public void removeSelection(int position)
      {
          selectionValueMap.remove(position);
          notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
      public void removeItem()
      {
          Set<Integer> mapKeySet = selectionValueMap.keySet();
          Iterator keyIterator = mapKeySet.iterator();
          while(keyIterator.hasNext())
          {
              int key = (Integer) keyIterator.next();
              Log.d("key", Integer.toString(key));
              DataValueList.remove(key);
              //DataValueList.remove(selectionValueMap.get(key));
          }
          notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)     vContext.getSystemService(vContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
          TextView tx = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          tx.setText(DataValueList.get(position));

          if(selectionValueMap.get(position) != null)
          {
              tx.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);//Choose Any Color
          }
          return convertView;
      }


  }
  ```

Comment: even i selected an item , it is not highlighted

Comment: long press on item, it will show to Context Action Bar for your listview

Comment: I mean I did long press and i also get the title changed according to the item that i selected but this selected item is not highlighted at all

Comment: IndexOutOfBound exception occurs when i delete items from listView

Comment: Updated Code for Selection HighLights with Green Color. and made changes for removing Selected Item.now try.sorry for the delay